# How to prevent double click in redux-form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a form and some buttons which are not related to the form. Also I have a blur validation on fields of the form. When field of the form is focused and I'm clicking on none-form button first time I fire blur action of redux-form field. And only on second click the button onClick is working. I want to fire onClick of none-form button on first click(when redux-form field blur action is firing). What should I do?

UPD: So far the best option is to replace onClick with OnMouseDown

Comment: Can you provide the code in the blur function? Are you stopping event propagation in the blur event handler?

Comment: i pass to my component default blur handler from redux-form's `input.blur` that dispatches `@@redux-form/BLUR`. I need it to handle validation. So far it works with onMouseDown but should I use something like `(e) => e.stopPropaganation(); input.onBlur(e.target.value)` instead(like onBlur handler)?  Why will it help?

Comment: No, you don't want to stop event propagation. That will probably make things worse. Does this issue help: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/860?